# What is involved in switching a project from Sql Server LocalDB to SQLite

Tags: .net, sqlite, localdb

I am considering converting a project that currently uses Sql Server LocalDB over to SQLite. (My goal is performance improvements).

I am using Entity Framework 6 and codefirst migrations. The project is a personal, WPF, .Net 4.52, single computer, single user trading application of which I have full control over. I do not need to keep or retain any existing databases. That is, in switching, I can trash any old databases.

On the surface of things from my noobie perspective it looks quiet simple. Just implement the system.data.sqlite package from nuget. Modify the connection strings. Allow the migrations to create the new database. And boo yah...

My question is, What are the differences I am likely to encounter? 
For example, Is any of my LINQ code going to need to be changed? Am I going to encounter difficulties with different data types? What other difficulties might I face?

Comment: Have you investigated what is currently the reason for the performance issues? I'd say it's quite difficult for anyone to give tips without knowing where the problem is

Comment: Hiya James, thank you. I haven't yet. The work is in progress and I may not experience performance issues. I am research if I need to preempt a change early. Perhaps, I should wait and solve the problem if it arrises. My biggest point of processing will be calculating moving averages, bollenger bands and various indicators on price/timeseries data. Typically, 250milliseconds apart over 24 hours. (Its a sports trading app) I figured I probably should be exploring database alternatives before getting really deep into the project then finding out I have to change a whole bunch of things.

Comment: Just run all your tests and see what breaks. (You have a bunch of automatic tests, haven't you?)

Comment: I have tests in place. Fairly rudamentary though. I'm to some degree a noob. It sounds like I'll have to just go and do it and see what happens :) So that's what I'll do. Thank you.